# Copy content of ArrayList to another with different object

Tags: java

I have two objects who share the same fields: `Livre` and `LivreVO`.

How can I copy the content of `List<Livre>` to `List<LivreVO>`?

For example:

```
List<Livre> liste = service.getListeLivre();
List<LivreVO> listeVO = new ArrayList<LivreVO>(liste);
```

Comment: You can't, unless both classes share some common super-type.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov Even if they have the same fields ?

Comment: Java does not support duck typing in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the two classes Livre and Livre0 share a common super-type; you can't (easily).

What you can do:

```
List<Livre0> listeV0 = new ArrayList<>();
for (Livre livre : service.getListeLivre()) {
  Livre0 copy = new LivreV0(...);
  listeV0.add(copy);
}
```

In other words: you have to create **new** objects; and *how* you do that depends on your existing classes. A *reasonable* approach could be to have a constructor within `LivreV0` that takes a `Livre` object; and fetches all relevant properties from there.

Worst case, you might want to look into **reflection**. That would allow you to basically query all fields in a Livre-Object; and use that information to push values into equally named fields in a Livre0-Object.
Works, but cumbersome and error-prone.

And: it might also be worth **stepping back** here. Alone the idea of having **two** different classes that have the **same** fields ... sounds like a design **problem**. Thus the real answer might be to rethink your object model. Probably you should have a **third** class that contains your all those properties that need to be **common** for Livre and Livre0. Meaning: instead of **duplicating** all that information, you push that data into `Common` objects; and then your Livre and Livre0 objects "point" to a `Common` object.

Comment: @kh.tab then maybe learn about inheritance and stop copy-pasting classes with the same fields?!

Comment: Thanks i understand now

Comment: @kh.tab depending what relationship your classes have you should look into object composition too. [Inheritance vs. composition](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that there is a `LivreVO` constructor which accepts `Livre`:

```
LivreVO(Livre object){
  // copy common fields. 
}
```

Now we can transform `List<Livre> liste` into `List<LivreVO> listeVO`:

```
List<LivreVO> listeVO = liste.stream().map(LivreVO::new).
                              collect(Collectores.toList());
```

Or you can just create new `LivreVO` objects and populate them manually:

```
List<LivreVO> listeVO = liste.stream().map(livre -> {
                           LivreVo tmp = new LivreVo();
                           tmp.setCommonField(livre.getCommonField());
                           //...
                           retrun tmp;
                        }).collect(Collectores.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some mechanism to convert a Livre into a LivreVO, then do something like that:

```
List<LivreVO> listeVO = new ArrayList<>();
for (Livre l: service.getListeLivre()) {
    listVo.add(convert(l));
}
```